# Formula for the $n$-th derivative of $f(x)=e^x(x^2-5x+7)$

Tags: calculus

I am sorry for the vague title, I have thought for a while how to best describe this issue that I need help with, but I couldn't find a good way.

> Let 
>   $$f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R, f(x)=e^x(x^2-5x+7)$$
>
> I want to figure out the general formula for $f^n(x)$, which means the derivative of order $n$ of $f(x)$.

I calculated the first 10 terms and the thing I am having issues with is the "free term" of the quadratic equation, let me show you.

$$f'(x)=e^x(x^2-3x+2)$$
$$f''(x)=e^x(x^2-x-1)$$
$$f'''(x)=e^x(x^2+x-2)$$
$$f^4(x)=e^x(x^2+3x-1)$$
$$f^5(x)=e^x(x^2+5x+2)$$
$$f^6(x)=e^x(x^2+7x+7)$$
$$f^7(x)=e^x(x^2+9x+14)$$
$$f^8(x)=e^x(x^2+11x+23)$$
$$f^9(x)=e^x(x^2+13x+34)$$
$$f^{10}(x)=e^x(x^2+15x+47)$$
$$.....$$
The formula for the general term should be the following.
$$f^n(x)=e^x\big(x^2+x(2n-5)+(n^2-6n+7)\big)$$
The first two terms are easy to tell, the first one($x^2$) never changes and second one($x$) grows linearly, but the free term changes based on the values of the previous derivatives, so it grows (quadratically? Is this the term?).

I appreciate any and every help!

Comment: [General Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule), note that the $k$th derivative of a quadratic is 0 for $k\geq 3$.

Comment: I am really surprised there is a rule that describes this exact thing. Really interesting, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $a_n$ is the coefficient of $x$ in $f^n$ and $b_n$ is the constant term, we have:
$$b_n=b_{n-1}+a_{n-1}=b_{n-1}+2n-7$$
That is, $b_n$ is $b_0$ plus the sum of the $n$ first terms of the arithmetic progression $2n-7$.

This is
$$b_n=7+\frac{-5+2n-7}2\cdot n=n^2-6n+7$$

Comment: How do I figure $a_{n-1}=2n-7$?

Comment: $a_{n-1}=2(n-1)-5=2n-7$